# Turn computer into projector

Tags: windows-7, networking, external-display

Is there any built-in method that can turn a PC into a network projector?  I have a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with SP2 and Concurrent RDP Patcher.

I tried to look in Devices and Printers and didn't see an option to share the monitor.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What Techie007 said. Also a new account with "I heard product X is great!" raises some eyebrows. Especially without a disclaimer "I do not work for the people who make product X".

Comment: @Hennes, you may want to re-read the question (and check their [profile](http://superuser.com/users/281513/user281513)) before making implications.

Comment: I did, though I missed the 'not' in 'not very good'. My bad. I just tried to be helpful and explaining.

Comment: Hennes, I'm not saying any product is great or deliberately trying to find an insult for any product. You may want to reread my question.

Comment: The computer I have has multiple user accounts. I did a test on the Concurrent RDP Patcher and found that when I logged on to a user profile that was logged on in the background, the connection showed the user at the exact state it was when I switched user. I can not log on to my current active user profile though.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/products/free/) (it's free) on the 'projector', and connect to it with any computer you want. Then you can control anything (like a powerpoint) remotely, as it doesn't black out the computer you're connecting to.

Comment: Almost any VNC software will also do...

Comment: Yeah, but is there any built in feature?

Comment: Nope, you need to install something extra. Remote Desktop comes close to what you want but blanks the client screen.